# How not to have click twice to pause youtube videos

Tags: safari, mouse

Im a complete new Mac user.

When I have a youtube video playing in safari window, and I'm typing an email in a different safari window, I have to click twice to pause the youtube video, once to focus the window, and once again to actually pause the video. But if I double click the video it will switch to full screen! I have to click twice with a pause...

Is there any configuration I can change so that I only have to click once?

I Googled the problem and I see a lot about "focus follows mouse" plugins, but I'm not sure if that's what I need, I just want the click to go through, instead of a "dedicated focus click", because that doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+Click on pause button. By default <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+Click does not activate window under the click.

Comment: I always forget about that - I've learned to use it for window resizing, but 30 years of Mac without that feature has left me rather set in my ways ;)

Comment: it's not perfect but it works ! Anyway I can make command click focus the window ?

Comment: Cmd click specifically does not focus the window, it acts directly on where you click - it's relatively new behaviour, afaik

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer No, to bring window to focus You have to click again (without CMD). Tetsujin I think this worked in 10.6 also, maybe earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard Mac behaviour - the first click activates the window, next click acts on the clicked object.

Since Yosemite, one or two aspects of the OS now seem to accept a first click - close boxes on unfocussed windows etc, but it's still not global.

Comment: Thx for the answer, that's pretty sad, do you know of any plugins that could fix this ?

Comment: Mateusz has it - it's one I forget about, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

With some inspiration from [Mateusz Szlosek answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173619/how-not-to-have-click-twice-to-pause-youtube-videos/173622#173622), I downloaded [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) to hook up Two Finger Click to <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+Left Click. It does pretty much exactly what I want, the fact that I don't lose focus is actually pretty useful to.

Edit: already switched it to Three Finger Click because Two finger click gives to many false positives :)