# Mac OS Two Monitors Chrome YouTube Video Requires Second Click

Tags: keyboard, video, google-chrome, shortcut

Hey all I'm new to using Macbooks (I'm on the M1 Macbook Air), this is my issue in short: when Chrome isn't in focus on my second monitor, and I try to play a video again by switching focus from my other screen, it doesn't play, but after a second click, then it plays. I know it's a small thing, but because of the frequency of when I do this, it's super annoying. How can I have it play in just one click?

I've also tried double clicking fast, but it instead just maximized the video which I don't want. So I'm stuck actually clicking first, and then waiting the half second before my second click - I switch between the screen really often and pause very often to take notes, so it adds up.

Here's a detailed breakdown if the issue didn't quite make sense:

Given:

- I have 2 monitors (1 monitor being the Macbook itself and the other being an external monitor)
- On monitor 1, I have Chrome full screened with a paused video (which is not full screened)
- On monitor 2, I have a Word document that is currently in focus (for taking notes)

When:

- I click the video on monitor 1

Then:

- The video doesn't play, but requires a second click

I did some googling but couldn't find a relevant answer, ideally this would act like in Windows, where you don't have to click twice with no modification keys pressed. I saw [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173619/how-not-to-have-click-twice-to-pause-youtube-videos) answer and the command+click does not work either :(

Comment: It is like this only, i mean not only in youtube videos, but anywhere you have a 'link' you would have to click the screen twice to make it click. 

And the answer you have linked says that you should click  cmd+click  on the 'play button' that totally works, you can try it!

Comment: Ahh, that does work - confirmed. For some reason I imagined the "play button" to just be in the middle of the screen. Thank you! This will actually help a lot for now, though if anyone has a true solution, that would be even better! Thanks!